# Create class in foreach loop using the element as name

Tags: c#, class, foreach

I'm currently writing a program that reads and manipulates an Excel file. To make things easier to track I'm trying to define a class for every element/row of the Excel File. This is the code that I tried to use (using the IronXL Library):

`foreach(var c in FoodXL["B2:" + "B" + Convert.ToString(CellLength + 2)]) {
                FoodItem c.Text = new FoodItem();
            }`

However, I keep getting errors because when I use 'c.Text' it thinks that I'm trying to change the variable Text of class c and when I use '(c.Text)' I get error CS1955. It is possible to define classes and name them using instructions in a foreach loop?

Comment: What do you mean by `defining and naming classes in a foreach loop`?

Comment: @aage I want to create a class in a foreach loop. So, I want to create 1 class for every element of the list with the name of that element as the name of the class.

Comment: You can not dynamically create classes in `c#`. If you want to store and retrieve something by name, could't you use a `Dictionary<string,FoodItem>` where the `key` is the name and the `value` the `instance` (so the `FoodItem`)? How do you need this data later on?

Comment: If all the rows have the same structure you just need one class and then create multiple instances of that one class for each row. If the rows are all somehow different, maybe you need [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).

Comment: @aage Thanks for the help. Never even heard of Dictionary. What I'm trying to do is take the information in the excel file (amounts of items) and add to those values. For context: I'm writing a program that can scan in receipts and note down all of the things I would have left in the house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your class beforehand, you cannot declare it dynamically. For example:

```cs
public class FoodItem {
    public string Text;
}
```

and then, upon parsing your file, you can instantiate it like this:

```cs
foreach(var c in FoodXL["B2:" + "B" + Convert.ToString(CellLength + 2)]) {
    FoodItem foodItem = new FoodItem() { Text = c };
}
```